# Looking for a "undo" for file with holes (GNU)

Tags: command-line, sparse-files

Linux supports sparse files aka 'file with holes'

Note following commands

```
alias mystat='stat -c "%n: %B*%b blocks %s bytes"'

dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024k seek=4096 count=0 of=file-with-holes

ls -l file-with-holes
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4294967296 Feb 25 18:33 file-with-holes

mystat file-with-holes
file-with-holes: 512*0 blocks 4294967296 bytes

cp file-with-holes other-file

mystat other-file
other-file: 512*0 blocks 4294967296 bytes

cat file-with-holes > file-without-holes

mystat file-without-holes
file-without-holes: 512*8388608 blocks 4294967296 bytes
```

The cat command removed all  holes from the file.

Is there a way to get the holes back?

Comment: I see you deleted you answer but check out `bsdtar -S` - this will create sparse files on extraction (unlike GNU tar). Not really the answer for a full fs, but maybe good if restoring a backup. Also see `cpio --sparse`.

Comment: Thanks, there is also a `-S` for `rsync`. I already saved a nuber of hundreds gigs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cp --sparse=always file-without-holes another-file-with-holes
```

Example:

```
$ cp --sparse=always file-without-holes another-file-with-holes
$ du --apparent-size another
16384   another-file-with-holes
$ du another-file-with-holes
0   another-file-with-holes
```

Comment: That is a GNUism.

Comment: @vonbrand, any suggestions for commands that have POSIX options for copying sparse files like this? I can't find any.

Comment: @vonbrand The question assumes Linux. I don't think there's a Busybox solution.